# Show state of menu as active

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I have made the submenus with 'menu alias' type links, but when I go to a page, it won't give it the state 'active'/'current' like it normally would on a normal 'single article'.
i have used a menu module called 'Mega Menu'. Many thanks.

Comment: A menu alias is just a redirect to another menu item, like a single article menu item. Can you be more specific about what your menu alias is redirecting you to? It's THAT menu item that should host the active / current state.

Comment: Have you got a link to your website?

Answer (score 1):

That's likely a bug in the "Mega Menu" module. You can contact the developer of the extension and ask to get it fixed.

The core menu module has been fixed with Joomla 3.3.4 (see [PR 3911](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3911))